# Deja Dup fails to restore because it can't write to the directory

Tags: permissions, restore, deja-dup

Installed Ubuntu 18.04 from a USB drive and wanted to restore a directory from the external backup drive that had been done previously on 17.10. After selecting the files listed  by Deja Dup the restore failed because it couldn't write to the existing target directory.
The backed-up directory was /var/www/html and I was restoring certain files in that directory to the 18.04 directory /var/www/html.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to my problem was in a post that  said to forget duplicity and use the deja-dup command line to restore a file. That worked!
eg., deja-dup --restore /path/FILENAME
As in the post...Thanks to FEDORA